# ¿Por qué pasa al return directamente antes de llamar el webservice con Alamofire 4?

Tags: json, ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

Mi problema es, que al momento de llamar esa función de un ViewController pasa directamente al return, y necesito regresar ya sea true o false después que corra el webservice. 
Esta es la clase donde tengo mi función:

```
class Services{
    func login(User: String, Password: String) -> Bool{
        let parameters: Parameters = ["cLogin":User,
                                      "cPassword":Password]
        Alamofire.request(oSS.uLogin, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let result = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                var errorMessage = result.object(forKey: "IsError")! as! Bool
                if(errorMessage == false){
                    self.Change = true
                }else{
                    self.Change = false
                    print("Message: ", errorMessage)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return Change
    }
```

Aqui mando a llamar la funcion desde mi View Controller:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

let oS = Services()
        @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
        oS.login(User: tUser.text!, Password: tPassword.text!)
        if oS.Change == false {
            print("False")
        }

    }
   }
```

Comment: Desarrolla un poco más tu pregunta... ¿Qué quieres hacer con esos hilos?
Alamofire directamente ejecuta la request en el background y devuelve la response en el main thread...

Comment: Edité mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decía en mi comentario, Alamofire se ejecuta en el background, con lo cual, la función es llamada, pero no espera a que el servicio web devuelva el resultado.

Deberías cambiar tu función para que devuelva una closure con el resultado:

```
func login(User: String, Password: String, completion: (Bool)->()) {
    let parameters: Parameters = ["cLogin":User,
                                  "cPassword":Password]
    Alamofire.request(oSS.uLogin, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let result = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
            var errorMessage = result.object(forKey: "IsError")! as! Bool
            if(errorMessage == false){
                completion(true)
            }else{
                completion(false)
                print("Message: ", errorMessage)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

  let oS = Services()
    @IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
        oS.login(User: tUser.text!, Password: tPassword.text!) { result in
            if result == false {
                print("False")
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Gracias, me fue muy útil!

Answer (score 0):

El motivo por el cual se va al return, es por que es el siguiente comando a ejecutarse en el thread, la instruccion de alamofire se executa en un thread secundario.